# Sender score and side effects releated to mailinator.com or maildrop.cc or any other spam eater tool

Tags: email, spam, reputation

I have looked around, however, I can't find accurate information if the Sender Score could be affected if I send hundreds of transactional emails daily to mailinator.com or maildrop.cc or any spam eater tool. I'm in a testing phase and sometimes I face a scenario where I need to send tons of emails through the email service.

I recall from the past a previous discussion with email solution representative, because initially those emails are not reaching such domains. They explained us that in some way our reputation could be affected. Then they removed from the blacklist those domains and we started to receive emails.

So I have tried find anywhere some insights if really there are side effects of sending to domains like mailinator.com or maildrop.cc and if there's such testing permitted volume.

Can anyone point me to the correct place where to look at?

Thanks.